# How to achieve the choking condition at the orifice?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid

I have a geometry featuring two inlets. One inlet is designated for gaseous Ethylene, and the other is for gaseous Oxygen. During my computational analysis, I am unable to incorporate the complete plenum due to computational resource limitations. Consequently, the resulting geometry, shown in the Figure, it has plenum conditions applied at the inlet boundary patches.

My objective is to establish a choke condition at the location marked by the dotted red line, as per the choke condition equation provided.

$$
mass flow rate (m) = \frac{A*p \sqrt{(\frac{\gamma}R)\frac{2}{(\gamma+1)}^{\frac{\gamma+1}{\gamma-1}}}}{\sqrt{T}}
$$

When I substitute all the constants ($\gamma$, $A$ and $R$), the equation appears as follows:

$$
                m \propto \frac{p}{\sqrt{T}} 
$$

Here, the mass flow rate is given and constant, the pressure is automatically acquired from the solver, and I set the temperature at 300 K. Despite these settings, I have been unable to achieve the choke condition at the throat location. I seek guidance on the procedure I need to adopt to achieve the choke condition at the throat.
[image]

Comment: I suggest you read up on Mach choking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choked_flow so that you can understand your formula.